# Umbraco (4.7) in a subfolder or virtual directory?

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, umbraco

Has anyone successfully installed Umbraco 4.7 into a sub folder or virtual directory? I am at the end of my wits here. I have had success with neither.

I am trying to get it working so mydomain.com/umbracoTest is the umbraco site.

What I find happens every time is it can never find the umbTopNavigation.xslt when I install the starter kit, I find out after changing skins, it creates a sub directory in my umbraco folder with the same name as the install folder (so if my virtual directory points to C:\apps\umbracoTest, it creates a folder C:\apps\umbracoTest\umbracotest) which has the XSLT folder, css, scripts, images, etc. So I copy those out to the root app directory and hey I no longer get that error and content actually loads, but none of the images/css/scripts work because I can see it's looking for them in mydomain.com/images instead of mydomain.com/umbracoTest/images.

Can Umbraco actually function not a the root level of a domain? How the heck can I get it working?

NOTE: I configured all the settings properly in IIS. IUSR, IIS_IUSRS, and Network Service have full control of the directory, also the virtual directory is configured as an application using .NET 4.0 Integrated.

Answer (score 1):

No you should be able to install Umbraco in any subfolder but you have to set a hostname for your site.

Check this screencast, http://cultiv.nl/blog/2010/2/1/screencast-installing-umbraco/

Or this post, [Umbraco configured with IIS 7 having hard time with the site URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390498/umbraco-configured-with-iis-7-having-hard-time-with-the-site-url/17407630#17407630)

Comment: I am not installing it locally but on Windows Server 2008, does that method still apply? I've only done domain level hostnames before. So I should be able to put the ip of my server and the text can be `www.mydomain.com/umbracoTest` and that will work?

Comment: this didn't work. The server's IP is using IPv6 so I am not sure if that could be an issue? I configured the umbraco site as a virtual directory with subfolder being /cms (started fresh), did all the permissions again, in the hosts file I put the IP and then for the URL I put (www.mydomain.com/cms), however upon trying to load it I get the error: Failed to map the path '/cms'.

Comment: Could you add the answer in the question too instead of just a link? e.g. just mention where to set a hostname for the site?

Comment: @DaviddCeFreitas Updated answer with link to another answer on this site.

Answer (score 1):

In umbracoSettings.config there is a setting ResolveUrlsFromTextString that must be turned on for sites in a virtual directory.

Have you turned that on?

Answer (score 0):

By default Umbraco does not support to installed out of the box in a sub-folder as the Umbraco application will expect everything being relative located from root (/) but in theory you could update all of the links but that would not be a job I would do.

Easiest it to setup your site as a sub-domain instead like: umbracotest.mydomain.com