# installing umbraco on a subdomain that is a subfolder of the root

Tags: iis-7.5, umbraco

I have a similar problem as here [Umbraco (4.7) in a subfolder or virtual directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085207/umbraco-4-7-in-a-subfolder-or-virtual-directory) but not exactly.

I have an umbraco installation running as a subdomain (newmain.mydomain.com).  The way we are doing subdomains on my server is to create an application under the main site then let the web.config at the root take care of the url rewriting.  This is working fine for all my other subdomains, but umbraco doesn't seem to like it at all.  Can someone point me in the right direction in the umbraco web.config (or elsewhere) to help me make this work?  Perhaps I need better rewriting on the web.config at the root, but I'm unsure what changes to make.

I'm reluctant to create another root level website for various reasons.

Comment: Pretty much all of our Umbraco staging sites start off as subdomains and we haven't experienced unique problems to subdomains, or any need to modify the `web.config` any differently from a root level domain, nor should there be a need to write URL rewrite rule to handle it. Could you elaborate on *umbraco doesn't seem to like it at all*? Try separating it from your main site (in IIS and on your file system) by creating it as a separate website, but with the appropriate hostname in IIS.

Comment: I think the problem is having it as a subfolder of the root domains subfolder and using URL rewriting for the subdomain.  I've created a new website in IIS as a subdomain (which I didn't want to do) and that is working better.  As for the "doesn't seem to like it at all comment" that was because my routes started looking like newmain.mydomain.com/newmain.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up moving this to a more standard style subdomain.  I think it's disappointing that it must be configured this way.