# No template exists to render the document at url '/'

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

In Umbraco, why does one get this error on a new deployment or machine that is pointing to an existing umbraco database and existing content?

> Page not found
>
> **No template exists to render the document at url '/'.**
>
> In addition, no template exists to render the custom 404.
>
> This page can be replaced with a custom 404. Check the documentation
>   for "custom 404".
>
> This page is intentionally left ugly ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it was doing that was because the domain name wasn't setup correctly.
I was using a custom domain to host the site, and umbraco was obviously not matching the incoming request to a site in the CMS.

By going to the Site and right clicking -> Culture and Hostnames, I could set the hostname.

As per this answer: [Umbraco configured with IIS 7 having hard time with the site URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390498/umbraco-configured-with-iis-7-having-hard-time-with-the-site-url/17407630#17407630)

```
Did you set your hostname in Umbraco?

Right click on the site root in your solution and click "Culture and hostnames"
```

[image: right click]

```
Fill out your hostnames and save
```

[image: culture and hostnames]

Comment: Do you have a multi-site installation? You shouldn't usually need to add hostnames if your install only has a single site.

Comment: Multi-site installation yes, I probably should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 3):

One other thing to check is that if the page is published you have a template selected for the page or you will also get a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't have a template, but I notice that one isn't required. (Only for previewing it seems?)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and force a full republish and refresh of content, use http://example.com/umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true assuming your installation wnet well and you can see the pages in the content area. As for the 404 you need to set one your self and assing it in the umbraco config file.

Comment: Thanks for the lead, but it wasn't the cause in this case, although it does seem to be recommended a lot as a solution to umbraco issues.